# How do I see all of my privileges?

Tags: support, privileges

The title pretty much speaks for itself because all I want to know is how to view my privileges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full list of privileges can be viewed [in the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). This page also has checkmark indicators next to each privilege you have.

Comment: Note you can get to this page from the Achievements menu in the top bar which has links to privileges and badges at the top.

Comment: Thanks.........